# android eclipse text file colour change based on value

Tags: android, eclipse

hey there I'm trying to create a traffic light system for android but not having much luck

you see I want the text to change based on the value inside it

but I'm also getting this these values from a pre-existing text file i have previously created
I want the text file to be green if the value is 0 to 2 Amber if its 2 to 6 and red if its higher

any ideas thanks
this is the code im using
public class View1 extends Activity {

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
// @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view);

    readFromFile();

    }


    public void readFromFile()
    {
        //put your code in here
        //you may want to use a buffered reader and check out your bytes!
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);

        String LOC = "Newcas.txt";
        String NAME = LOC;

        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = openFileInput(NAME);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fileIn);

            char[] inputBuffer = new char[250];
            String s =" ";

            int charRead;

            while ((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer))>0)
            {
                String readString = String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charRead);
                s += readString;

                inputBuffer = new char[250];
            }

            tv1.setText(s);

        } catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        setContentView(tv1);
    }
    public class ColorChangingTextView extends TextView {
        //Default constructor for creating view from layout. You can add the rest if you want.
        public ColorChangingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int before, int after) {
            int val = Integer.parseInt(text.toString());
            if(val >= 0 && val <= 2)
                super.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            else if(val >= 2 && val <= 6)
                super.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 126, 0)); //RGB(255, 126, 0) is Amber
            else if(val >= 6)
                super.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }}
```

my layout file view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Loc01"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="@string/Location1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Loc02"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="@string/Location2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Loc03"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="@string/Location3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Loc04"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="@string/Location4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Loc05"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="@string/Location5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this i a example from my txt file
Date:   20/1/2012   Time:   12:51,
Rain fall:  5cm

Date:   22/1/2012   Time:   12:50,
Rain fall:  4cm

Comment: I assume you meant a TextView when you said textfile?

Comment: no the values come froma pre-existing text file as now shown above sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

This class can do the job:

```
public class ColorChangingTextView extends TextView {
    //Default constructor for creating view from layout. You can add the rest if you want.
    public ColorChangingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int before, int after) {
        int val = Integer.parseInt(text.toString());
        if(val >= 0 && val <= 2)
            super.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        else if(val >= 2 && val <= 6)
            super.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 126, 0)); //RGB(255, 126, 0) is Amber
        else if(val >= 6)
            super.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how to put it in code (XML layout):

```
<your.package.name.ColorChangingTextView id="@+id/idForTextView"
    text="This is some text"
    ....
    />
```

Comment: sorry about this but how would i put this into my code so it works?

Comment: that just causes the file to get a error and not open up, iv updated my code to include my xml file and how iv edited my.java file, would you mind looking through it and find out whats wrong? apoligies for this, im fairly new to androide development

Answer (score 0):

Heres a small bit of code that may help you. I'll make it a text counter based on an EditText.

First you gotta declare your textview in the activity

```
    TextView txtCount; //txtCount is an arbitrary name
    EditText smsMessage; //This is the EditText we'll be watching.
```

So in your main activity you'll want:

```
extends Activity implements TextWatcher
```

In the onCreate, you need this:

```
    txtCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCount); // 1
    txtCount.setText(Integer.toString(140)); // 2
    txtCount.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#888888")); // 3
    smsMessage.addTextChangedListener(this); //4
```

1: where txtCount is the id of the textview

2: This sets the text. You would have to pull the initial value from your file OR just set 
one.

3: Changes the default color, could use Color.GREEN in your case.

4: In this case, we're following the changing of an EditText, though in your case you'd have 
to look into how to pull that information from a file.

Later on, you'll need to add these:

```
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable smsMessage) { // 1
    int count = 140 - smsMessage.length(); //2
    txtCount.setText(Integer.toString(count));
    txtCount.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#888888"));//3
    if (count < 0)
        txtCount.setText("2 SMS"); //4
    if (count < -140)
        txtCount.setText("3 SMS");

}

  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

 } //5

  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

} //5
```

1: The Editable smsMessage is something you would have to change, again because we're using an EditText to check the status here.

2: This simply decreases the number displayed

3: More color changing.

4: And in this if statement, if the number is below 0, then it changes completely.

5: These are just mandatory methods you can leave blank

Now, this code is extremely messy. And deals with EditText, but hopefully it will set you on the right track.